# Keyboard layout automatically changed

Tags: laptop, keyboard-layout

My keyboard layout changed by itself. The functionality of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys swapped, the functionality of <kbd>Delete</kbd> and <kbd>Pause</kbd> keys swapped and my arrow keys have an added functionality of controlling the brightness and volume of the system.

Since I'm using a laptop, the features of the function keys have also been interchanged, for example the volume control now switches the projector control. I also tried testing the keyboard on a different OS, but got the same results.

I'm using a HCL laptop and the keyboard behavior is of a Dell Vostro — I have no idea how this happened.